# Parse error in Map Function over Trees

Tags: haskell, dictionary, tree

I've defined a polymorphic data type called `Tree a` as follows:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

I want to define a function `mapT` that takes a function and applies it to every data item of type `a` within a tree of type `Tree a`. The essential purpose of this function would be to operate on trees the same way the `map` function operates on list so I've written a function based off of that idea:

```
mapT :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapT f Leaf = Leaf
mapT f ((Tree a) left right) = (Tree a) (mapT f left) (mapT f right)
```

However, when I run this, I get a `Parse error in pattern: (Tree a)` and I can't figure out what's wrong. Does anyone have any idea how to get passed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

mapT :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapT f Leaf = Leaf
mapT f (Node a left right) = Node (f a)  (mapT f left) (mapT f right)
```

Note that your `Leaf` constructor doesn't have any data associated with is, so perhaps you really want:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node ...
```

with the corresponding change in `mapT`.

Also, once you have got `mapT` working for you, you should read up on the `Functor` type class, and why you might want to create a `Functor` instance for `Tree a`:

```
instance Functor Tree where
  fmap (Leaf ...)  = ...
  fmap (Node x l r) = Node ...
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `Tree` is a type constructor, not a data constructor. You probably meant `Node`.
2. The error message is trying to tell you that you can't have arbitrary application in a pattern. You can only match a fully applied constructor, so `(Node a left right)` is a valid pattern while `((Node a) left right)` is not, even though both are valid as expressions.
3. You'll need to apply `f` to `a` to get something of type `b` to put in the transformed node. Otherwise the type checker will complain that it can't match `a` with `b`.

The end result should look something like this:

```
mapT :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
mapT f Leaf = Leaf
mapT f (Node a left right) = Node (f a) (mapT f left) (mapT f right)
```